# Passing argument as HTML attribute

Tags: python, html, bottle

I am experimenting with Bottle and HTML to test HTTP GET and POST. I have written this code which requires user to enter a color name as parameter and if it is present in the pre defined list then it should print found and display the color. But I donot know how do I pass the argument. If I try default values like Orange, Red etc it works fine.

```
from bottle import*
import socket

@error(404)
def error404(error):
    return '<p align=center><b>Sorry, a screw just dropped.Well, we are hoping to find it soon.</b></p>'

@get('/New/rem_serv/:arg')
def nextstep(arg):
_colorlist=['Red','Green','Blue','Yellow','Orange','Black','White']

if arg in _colorlist:
    return "Found the same color \n","<p style='font-weight:bold; text-align:center; background-color:arg;'>" + str(arg)
else:
    return error404(404)

addrIp = socket.getaddrinfo(socket.gethostname(), None)
addrIp = addrIp[0][4][0]
run(host=addrIp, port=80)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is HTML and [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp).

```
<span style="color:red"><b>This is red</b></span>
```

Use [template](http://www.bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#tutorial-templates) to make pages.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like that :

```
@app.route('/New/rem_serv/:arg')
@view('template.tpl')
def nextstep(arg):
   _colorlist=['Red','Green','Blue','Yellow','Orange','Black','White']
    if arg in _colorlist: 
        context = {'result': "Found the same color %s" % arg}
     else:
        context = {'result': "color not found"}
    return (context)
```

you can also try with this :

```
from bottle import Bottle, run, view, request

app = Bottle()

@app.route('/New/rem_serv/')
@view('template.tpl')
def nextstep():
    """
    get the color from the url 
    http://127.0.0.1:8080/New/rem_serv?color=xxx
    """
    _colorlist=['Red','Green','Blue','Yellow','Orange','Black','White']
    if arg in _colorlist: 
        context = {'result': "Found the same color %s" % request.params.color}
     else:
        context = {'result': "color not found"}
    return (context)
```

then the rest is a question of template/html/css